# House 240 backup power to junction box from 120 inverter?

Tags: inverter, electrical

Main power outage happens frequently at my cabin in the woods.
I want to power LOW WATTAGE to both legs of the panel from a single 1500W inverter.  NO 240 will be attempted, but does anyone see a problem with temporary substitution of input to both legs at the same time?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't backfeed the grid

Comment: Note that [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com) will be more familiar with code and the safety issues with residential electrical work.

Comment: To simplify --- There is NO grid here .. it's a backup for my 240V inverter system

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer is purely technical, legal issues are something you would have to check with whatever code your jurisdiction enforces.

From a technical perspective there are a few things to be consider.

1. Currents will sum rather than cancel in the neutrals of "multiwire" circuits. This is unlikely to be an issue with such a small inverter but it's something to be aware of if you try to do this with something bigger.
2. How will the inverter respond to overloading if you forget to turn off high power equipment? presumablly it will trip out but tripping out frequently is unlikely to be good for the inverter.
3. If you have any equipment that uses both hots and the neutral how will it respond to this situation.
4. Whatever you do make sure you don't backfeed the grid. There should be a suitable switching/interlocking system in place to make sure that the grid and inverter are never connected to each other.

Comment: The only 220V device is a well pump, which would be disconnected before the backup inverter goes on. I couldn't think of a problem when no device attempts 220/240, but 240 inverter are way too expensive to be practical during outages. I only want to power a refrigerator, lights, and a TV. ~~~ THANKS